# Use Cell's Contents as Variable in String - Excel

Tags: excel-2010

I have a column of SKUS like so:

```
AD01
AD02
AD03
AD04
AD05
AD06
```

And a column containing a series of file paths like so:

```
'+/images/FloorShot/Rectangle/FLOORSHOT_RECTANGLE_AD01.jpg
'+/images/FloorShot/Rectangle/FLOORSHOT_RECTANGLE_AD02.jpg
'+/images/FloorShot/Rectangle/FLOORSHOT_RECTANGLE_AD03.jpg
'+/images/FloorShot/Rectangle/FLOORSHOT_RECTANGLE_AD04.jpg
'+/images/FloorShot/Rectangle/FLOORSHOT_RECTANGLE_AD05.jpg
'+/images/FloorShot/Rectangle/FLOORSHOT_RECTANGLE_AD06.jpg
```

I am looking to use the values in the SKU column as a variable like so:

```
'+/images/FloorShot/Rectangle/FLOORSHOT_RECTANGLE_"Sku Variable Here".jpg
```

What would be the best way to accomplish something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
="'+/images/FloorShot/Rectangle/FLOORSHOT_RECTANGLE_"&A1&".jpg"
```